# How to update the text of all EditTexts elements in a RecyclerView with two-way data binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, two-way-binding

I have an **RecyclerView** which holds some **CardViews** and each **CardView** contains **EditText** which *multiplies* the user given *amount* times a specific *rate* (the rate comes from an endpoint and the rate is different per row). For the **CardViews** I am using data binding.

Use case of the app:

The app should show how much for example 2, 7.89, 14.34, or 110 € are in other currencies.

1. User enters an **amount** (in the **EditText**) in any line, each line has a "**rate**" (rate comes from an API endpoint) field with a different value
2. The user entered **amount** gets multiplied by the "**rate**"
3. Each row in the **RecyclerView** should be updated

Now is the question how to update the text of all EditTexts elements in a **RecyclerView** with two-Way data binding

This is my data class for data binding:

```
data class CurrencyItem(
    var flag: String,
    var shortName: String,
    var fullName: String,
    var rate: Double
) : BaseObservable() {

    @Bindable
    var rateTimesAmount: String = (CurrencyApplication.userEnteredAmount * rate).toString()
        set(amount) {
            val amountAsDouble = amount.toDouble()
            val number2digits: Double = String.format("%.2f", amountAsDouble).toDouble()
            CurrencyApplication.userEnteredAmount = number2digits
            field = number2digits.toString()
            notifyPropertyChanged(BR.rateTimesAmount)
        }

}
```

This is my EditText in the item_currency.xml

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/currency_rate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLength="8"
                android:text="@={currency.rateTimesAmount}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="1183.068" />
```

This is my **Application** class which stores the user entered amount:

```
class CurrencyApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        var userEnteredAmount: Double = 1.00
    }

}
```

Here I access the **RecyclerView** through Kotlin Android Extensions:

```
recycler_view.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
            adapter = currencyAdapter
        }
```

Here is the **RecyclerView** from activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Here is the **Adapter** for the **RecyclerView**:

```
class CurrencyAdapter(
    val currencies: ArrayList<CurrencyItem>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CurrencyViewHolder>() {
    
    override fun getItemCount() = currencies.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CurrencyViewHolder {
        val itemCurrencyBinding: ItemCurrencyBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            R.layout.item_currency,
            parent,
            false
        )
        return CurrencyViewHolder(itemCurrencyBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CurrencyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemCurrencyBinding.currency = currencies[position]
    }

    fun setUpCurrencies(newCurrencies: List<CurrencyItem>) {
        currencies.clear()
        currencies.addAll(newCurrencies)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

class CurrencyViewHolder(val itemCurrencyBinding: ItemCurrencyBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemCurrencyBinding.root)
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? How to update the UI once input is taken? I am having same issue, LiveData observer is not getting called.  Can we trigger notify of LiveData change, without introducing new mutable with onTextChange? Please share your findings.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not found any proper solution for that problem

Answer (score 1):

You might probably want to create another `Observable` in -say- your viewModel or adapter and bind it as a variable to the adapter items.

Like so:

```kotlin
class CurrencyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<...>() {

    val rate = ObservableField(0.0)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater, viewType, parent, false)
        binding.setVariable(BR.rate, rate)
        return YourViewHolder(binding.root)
    }

}
```

If you encounter issues with other views eagerly updating the rate variable, try to making a custom data binding adapter to only allow views triggering the updates when they are in focus.

```kotlin
@BindingAdapter("android:textAttrChanged")
fun TextView.setOnTextAttrChangedInFocus(listener: InverseBindingListener) {
    addTextChangedListener(afterTextChanged = {
        if(isFocused) {
            listener.onChange()
        }
    })
}
```

*(example uses androidx.core extension)*

I hope it helps ;)

---

Check out [teanity](https://github.com/skoumalcz/teanity) it might help you figure out some stuff like this faster.

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. The second parameter of DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>() needs to be an Int. Where I get this Int from?

Comment: If you were to follow lint instructions you'd be able to solve that problem :) either ways it's my bad misleading you. look again at the line with inflation of the binding. I added inflater as the first parameter.

Comment: The app crash on the line:  val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ViewDataBinding>(inflater, viewType, parent, false) the message is Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Comment: Swap `viewType`, in my example, with `R.layout.item_currency`

Comment: Okay, but how would my method onBindViewHolder(holder: CurrencyViewHolder, position: Int)  look like? When I have to use holder.itemView this causes again new problems